# How can I determine in ItemSend event handler that mail item is a reply?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ms-office, add-in

I have such a class:

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void OnItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
    }

    private void OnNewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Reply += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(OnMailItemReply);
    }

    private void OnMailItemReply(object Response, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        var replyItem = Response as Outlook.MailItem;
        // Maybe I need to add or change in replyItem some property??
    }
}
```

I need to determine in OnItemSend event handler that mailItem is a reply message. Also I need to get there some value that I can add in OnMailItemReply method.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. Check the subject if it includes a RE or FW prefix.
2. Read the ConversationIndex property - if its length is 44 (22 bytes on Extended MAPI level), you have a first message in a conversation. If it is greater than that, you have a reply/forward. See [Tracking Conversations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583(v=office.15).aspx)  on MSDN